# "all actions" under my profile page shows two APPROVEs, but I only did one.

Tags: discussion, support, review

In this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469151), [Barry Cipra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86747) pointed out that "the edit history indicates [I] voted to approve the edit [my] comment is objecting to", which was "@[user274246](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/274246), note that significantly changing your original question would make all existing answers invalid. So I highly suggest that you write a separate post for a different question, if this is the case, next time it happens."  Barry said that the OP didn't make that edit, someone else did.  I am 100% sure though, that I did not make any silly mistakes with reviewing suggested edits.

So I went ahead and double-checked ["all actions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28816/jose-arnaldo-bebita-dris?tab=activity) under my profile page, it shows two **Approve**'s, whereas I only made one **Approve** (and that is for [Uri Goren](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/203575)'s suggested edit of [Scientifica](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/164983)'s answer to the question).

Here's my question:  Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?  Would it be possible to double-check the IP addresses that executed both **Approve**'s?

Thanks!

Comment: Note, the OP here and I have deleted our comments at the MSE question, to remove clutter that no one else there needed to read.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Barry!  =)

Comment: Incidentally, my guess on what happens is that after you approved Uri Goren's suggested edit of Scientifica's answer, the site automatically asked you to review his edit of the OP and you accidentally approved it as well, thinking you were just confirming your approval of the other edit.

Comment: For checking IPs you need to ask a moderator (flag or ask in the mod-room), not make a meta post about it.

Comment: I consider it more likely that you accidentally misclicked than that the software erroneously attributed the approval to your account. Don't make too much of it, misclicks happen.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone!